# Definition of an "Experiment" in Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, definition

One can define the fundamental concepts of probability theory (such as a probability measure, random variable, etc) in a purely axiomatic manner. However, when we teach probability, we start off with the notion of an "experiment", a concept it seems to me which is something akin to pornography: difficult to define, but you tend to know it when you see it.

So I am curious if there is a general definition of an experiment (or if it something really best regarded more as an explanatory construct). To try to define an experiment as a type of function seems difficult to me b/c it would require the notion of a "random function" of some type.

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would think that it would be the other way round - everyone understands what it means to roll a die, but the notion of a random variable is far less trivial.

To define an experiment, first define a "generator" - any physical or algorithmic method for producing $N$ numbers, such that $N$ tends to infinity, the numbers produced are distributed according to random variable $X$.

The production of any individual number using a generator is an experiment.

Answer (score 2):

I like the way it is defined in [Mathematical Statistics](http://books.google.com/books?id=9QHcJ8WQQ5UC) By Wiebe R. Pestman:

"A probability experiment is an experiment which, when repeated under the same conditions, does not necessarily give the same results"

[This](http://www.futureaccountant.com/probability/study-notes/trial-result-event-outcome.php) is useful as well.

Comment: My initial reaction is to say that I'm gobsmacked. I'll have to read the article though to understand the context (and his meaning) better. Is this what *most* statisticians take to be the definition, do you think?  Thanks

Comment: @JackZega By no means I'm a statistician. The above tries to convey  difference between deterministic experiment versus probability experiments. For example, if you try to measure voltage $V$ through a certain conductor with resistance $R$, you will always end up with the value $IR$ no matter what (this is a deterministic experiment ). One advice, the deeper you go the more hair you lose :)

Comment: I think this definition, taken out of its context, is quite dangerous. A probabilistic experiment must be infinitely repeatable. By infinitely repeatable we mean that each time you repeat the experiment, the sample space $\Omega$ (and so everything that follows from it) is constant. So actually, an experiment is a procedure that, when repeated keeps the sample space constant. Therefore the *possible* results of an experiments are always the same, but the actual result of a repetition of an experiment, *could* be different, if the experiment is a random experiment and not a deterministic one.

Answer (score 0):

“Experiment is a systematic way of varying all the factors of interest and observing impact of these all factors on the desired output.”

Answer (score 0):

While reading Grimmett & Welsh book, I found that an experiment is

> Any procedure whose consequences are not predetermined.

This is quite a restrictive definition in my opinion, because it excludes "deterministic" experiments where we can determine the final result 100% precision (because there is actually only one possible result). So to me, it the following definition given by Wikipedia seems more precise:

> Any procedure that is infinitely repeatable and whose outcomes are well-defined

This seems fine,  but it doesn't seem tremendously mathematical. So my guess is that the definition above is correct, and that is the definition used to define a sample space, outcomes, events, event space, probability measure, and so on. However, once we've defined all those mathematical structures, we can go back and say: actually, an experiment can easily be represented by a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$. This could be seen as a circular definition, but if you use the word "represented" instead of "defined" then you should be fine.

I just wrote an article (which I will extend soon, it's still under construction) in my website [SimpleAI](http://simpleai.it/en/learn/mathematics/probability/42-probabilistic-experiment)

[image: experiment_circular_definition]